# Navigation to a existing page in initial state

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am implementing a web application where through a Drawer, the user has access to the different functionalities.

Being in /home, what I want to do is:

The user clicks on the item X of the Drawer.
The user navigates to page A with offAndToNamed.
User does something and navigates from A to B with toNamed.
The user does something and navigates from B to C with toNamed.
The user clicks on item X in the Drawer again. What I want the application to do is to remove C, B and A by destroying their respective controllers; and to rebuild A from scratch, i.e. rebuild its controller.
I create all the controllers using GetBuilder. I don't explicitly use Get.Put.

I have tried:

`Get.offAllNamed(A)`: removes pages C, B, A with their respective controllers and navigates to A, but does not recreate the controller for A. This is obviously a problem.

`Get.offNamedUntil(A, (route) => route.settings.name == /home)`: Exactly the same as offAllNamed.

`Get.offAllNamed(/home); Get.offAndToNamed(A);` : Exactly the same as in the two previous cases.

`Get.offAllNamed('/home'); await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500)); Get.offAndToNamed(A)` :After destroying the three controllers, it builds the controller of A again. If instead of 500 milliseconds, I set 250 for example, it does not build the controller of A. What is the point of this behaviour? It's as if it hasn't completely destroyed the controller of A and you have to give it some time to do so. If I put an await on the offAllNamed, the following lines of code are never executed.

Any ideas for possible strategies?

Thank you very much